# Can Shotwell create a folder structure based on the date the photos were taken?

Tags: shotwell

All my photos are quite disorganized and I found this option in the settings dialogue to import pictures and create new folders using this pattern:  `/home/username/pictures/<year>/<month>/<day>`
Shotwell also asked whether to link or copy the pictures and I chose to copy, but nonetheless they aren't copied.

What can I do?

Comment: Works fine here. Is your `~/Pictures` a standard folder or a symbolic link to some space elsewhere (see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/797117))?

Comment: Its a standard folder. Does it matter that its a German system and hence the folder name is "Bilder" instead?

Comment: I doubt that, but you can try to choose a different folder like ~/test (something that's not a default folder, using *Edit → Preferences*).

Comment: This actually worked

Comment: Just to be sure: you don't try to import from a directory within `~/Pictures`, do you?

Comment: I still had problems with the pictures folder. I'll try tomorrow Thx anyways

Comment: No, not within /Pictures

Comment: I'd consider reporting a bug: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that Shotwell will only copy the photos if they are located outside your XDG Pictures directory (usually ~/Pictures).  If they are located inside your Pictures directory, Shotwell does not copy or reorganize them.  (It's a tough call, but there are a lot of people out there who absolutely, positively do NOT want us to move their photos because they've gone to a great deal of trouble to organize them in the first place.)

From reading the comments to your question, it looks like you hit on a workaround: import all the photos from a folder outside of Pictures and choose copy.  Unfortunately this means removing all the photos from Shotwell and re-importing them, meaning you lose all changes you've made to them (edits, tags, etc.)

We do have a ticket for exactly what you're looking for: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/shotwell/-/issues/1540  No idea when/if it'll be ready, but we'd like to offer it.

Comment: I updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

Move your images into a folder which isn't watched by Shotwell. Then start Shotwell and import the pictures (Ctrl+i). Now the pictures are new organized. I don't know about the problem [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/54172/46531), because I always edited the pictures by GIMP and saved them as a new file.