# Is there an easy way to reorganize tags in shotwell?

Tags: shotwell

I have a little over 800 photos with tags in shotwell. Recently, hierarchical tags have been added.

Now I want to reorganize my tags, e.g. I want a "People" tag and subtags of "Mom", "Dad", etc. Is there an easy way to do that, which doesn't involve me draging and dropping all the tags to their parent tags?

I have quite a lot tags and since every time I drag and drop a tag, I can only select one tag I want to move and I have to wait for shotwell finishing that operation. After it's done that, the list view scrolls back to the top, which means I have to scroll back down all the way to "People".

Example for clarification, *pretend* tags were directories. I want to do

```
mv tags/{mom,dad,brother} tags/people/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to select multiple tags in Shotwell.  There is an [open ticket](https://web.archive.org/web/20130530233659/http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/2275) on this feature, feel free to add a comment on it.

Update: the original link is no longer available, so an archived link to the bug report was linked.

Comment: I take that as a "no". Thanks for your answer! I guess I'll just have to do it by hand then

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. Shotwell can organize your photos into folders by time only. To achieve what you want you need to use the [Hierarchical Tags](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/tag.html) feature in Shotwell. This isn't exactly what you want though, so the short answer is no.

Have a look in Preferences/Library/Importing/Pattern: and click (Help) for a list of exactly the time-based metadata Shotwell can organize by.

If you are just wanting to separate out groups of photos to export, you can select a group of tagged photos and export them to a new folder. From there, you could manually reorganize your Pictures directory structure in the file browser.

~[ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87658/can-shotwell-create-a-folder-structure-based-on-the-event-a-photo-is-assigned-to)

Comment: oh yeah, hierarchical tags is exactly what I want and what I want to use.

However, I don't want to drag+drop all my tags Mom, Dad, Brother, etc to /People/{Mom,Dad,Brother} one at a time instead of in a batch (select multiple tags at once? Like with files in nautilus...)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not answering my initial problem. I was and am aware of hierarhical tags. What I want is to batch move a bunch of (currently toplevel) tags (mom, dad, brother) below another toplevel tag (people), so I have (people/mom, people/dad, people/brother, etc) and not have to do it by hand, since I have quite a lot of tags

Comment: Not in Shotwell, as you asked. Specific questions receive specific answers.  If you wanted to batch files or process them differently then you want something for Exif and IPTC-NAA data as well as analyse ICC profiles and meta-data.  Shotwell does not have the ablility. If you want something to do those thing with then look at this one.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/mapivi      It can be installed using "sudo apt-get install mapivi"

Comment: This may be a better fit than the last one and uses CLI it's called "tracker-tag" heres the manpage http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/tracker-tag.1.html   select your version at the top of the page