# How to create folders structure in shotwell

Tags: directory, shotwell, photo-management, photo, organizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Shotwell create a folder structure based on the event a photo is assigned to?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87658/can-shotwell-create-a-folder-structure-based-on-the-event-a-photo-is-assigned-to)

Trying to sort my photo folder  using shotwell, aside shotwell is good almost for everything... the events organization is just ridiculous. I have  number of photos taken across the various location on various dates and I don't care about dates. I want it simple to reproduce my folder tree. I don't wanna use tags as tags are needed for diversification of the  photo compilation. It would be ideal to have shotwell organizing folder similar to picasa folder tree.  Or at least possibilty to rename  events (years and months) and  easily move  photos  between events.
Tried various photo organizers such as gthumb, digikam, gwenwiew, darktable etc and all lack of stability or decent organizing possibilities. So far shotwell looks best but events organizing is just plain bad if you somehow work with photography.

The tree  should have  main folders then sub folders.

I'm quite surprised about lack of options in photo organizers and that keeps me from completely removing win from my pc's.

Any suggestions?